# inequality with complex numbers /absolute value

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Which subset of the complex plane satisfy
$$ \left| \frac{z+4}{z-4} \right| < 5$$

What I have tried: I wrote z as $z=a+bi$
thus
$$ \left| \frac{(a+bi+4)}{(a+bi-4)} \right| < 5$$

$$ \left| \frac{(a+4+bi)}{(a-4+bi)} \right| < 5$$
$$ \left| \frac{(a+4)+bi}{(a-4)+bi} \right| < 5$$

now I turn the denominator into a real number
$$  \left| \frac{[(a+4)+bi]\cdot [(a-4)-bi]}{[(a-4)+bi]\cdot [(a-4)-bi]}\right| < 5$$

in the denominator I would be having

$$  \left| \frac{[(a+4)+bi]\cdot [(a-4)-bi]}{(a-4)^2+b^2}\right| < 5$$

I can calculate the expression in the numerator, but I do not know how to proceed and if my approach up until here was even correct

**following the advice in the comments:**
$$\frac{|z+4|}{|z-4|} < 5\cdot$$
$$|a+bi+4| < 5\cdot|a+bi-4|$$
$$\sqrt{(a+4)^2+b^2} < 5 \cdot \sqrt{(a-4)^2+b^2}$$

I could square both sides,
then
$$ (a+4)^2+b^2 < 25 \cdot [(a-4)^2+b^2]$$

$$(a+4)^2-25 \cdot (a-4)^2 < 25b^2-b^2$$
$$(a+4)^2-25 \cdot (a-4)^2 < 24b^2$$

should I just divide the LHS by 24 and then take the root? then I would be havind $b=....$ for a given $a$?

Comment: Use this fact:    $$|\frac{z_1}{z_2}|=\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}$$ to simplify

Comment: @Khosrotash: thank you, should I do this before or after I multiplied $\cdot[(a-4)-bi]$?

Comment: You should do that right in the first step and then write. $z=a+ib$.

Comment: Geometrical interpretation: 
Let $M,A,B$ be the points with affixes $z,-4+0i,4+0i$ resp.
Your constraint is equivalent to 
$$\frac{d(M,A)}{d(M,B)}<5$$
which means that $M$ is inside a certain 'circle of Apollonius' passing in particuliar through point C=(6+0i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobius transformations take a line into a line or a circle, also a circle into a line or a circle.   Consider the closed disc  $w \leq  5.$   We know that $\frac{z+4}{z-4}$  lands some set in the interior of the disc.

The coefficient matrix being
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&4 \\
1 & -4 \\
\end{array}
\right)  $$

we get the inverse map as   having matrix coefficients
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-4&-4 \\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)  $$
or any scalar multiple of that, let us negate and use
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
4&4 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)  $$

Thus the inverse mapping is $\frac{4z+4}{z-1}.$   We need to know the images of disc interior points by this mapping. First we find out where the boundary circle goes: this will be  a line or a circle. $5$  maps to $6.$   Then $-5$  maps to $\frac{8}{3}.$  Next $5i$  maps to $\frac{96 - 40 i}{26}.$ For $-5i$  maps to $\frac{96 + 40 i}{26}.$

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, very nice solution! could you just tell me, after I have calculated the 4 boundaries, how can I write the complex subplane of the complex numbers?

Comment: @Inocenciaa   I just did 4  complex numbers. These lie on a circle;  with the usual $z = x + iy,$  this circle is $(x-x_0)^2 + ( y-y_0)^2 = R^2$  for some $x_0, y_0, R$.You really should check my calculations yourself I am pretty sure that $x_0 = \frac{13}{3} $  but I am still uncertain about $y_0.$  Once you are sure about the boundary circle, you still need to check inside or outside. Well, $0$ maps to $-4,$ outside the circle so the set you want is the exterior

Comment: thank you for help, I have calculated it and I also have $\frac{13}{3}$ for $x_0$ and $\frac{5}{3}$ for $R$, the solution for $y_0$ isn't a nice number, is there some way or program where I could check these calculations? but i do not understand quite well why the exterior is needed since I thought we need the interior points

Comment: @Inocenciaa  for example, $z=5$  is in the interior of the new circle. However, $\frac{5+4}{5-4} = 9$  has magnitude larger than $5.$   Possibly a better example, $z=4$  is also in the interior, but $\frac{4+4}{4-4} = \infty$ is outside.  This is one of the settings where the symbol $\infty$ is completely legitimate, as a point on the Riemann sphere.

Comment: @Inocenciaa  from outside the new circle: $z=8$  gives $\frac{8+4}{8-4} = 3$  which has magnitude below $5$

Comment: perfect, thank you